# How to sign in with email and password using firebase admin sdk in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'd like to create an Android application based on firebase. I'd like my application to autheticate users and check what their role is; so I used the method signInWithEmailAndPassword coming from the object FirebaseAuth.getInstance() to log.
Then I thought to save for each user a claim so I could keep track of their roles and to do this I use the Firebase admin SDK; problem is I no longer have the method signInWithEmailAndPassword on the class FirebaseAuth so I can't log my users.
What can I do to use both methods/fonctionnalities in the same project?
Thank you

Carlo

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Admin SDK in an Android app. It can only be used in back-end, server-side applications. You can implement a back-end service to set the custom claims as follows:

```
// Assuming the idToken is the authenticated user's ID token
// sent by the Android client:
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
try {
  FirebaseToken token = auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(token.getUid(), myClaims);
} catch (FirebaseAuthException ex) {
  // Handle error
}
```