# Add Firebase auth and Firebase admin in same Android Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to use both `Firebase Auth` and `Firebase Admin` dependency in my project. So i have added below dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.2'
```

But i can't use below method from `firebase auth`

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

I can only have methods of `FirebaseAuth` from `firebase-admin` dependency.
Some available methods are:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid);
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid);
```

If i remove `firebase-admin` dependency I can use `getCurrentUser`, `signOut` and other methods from `firebase-auth`

Its like both dependency have same package FirebaseAuth class with different implementation. With some search i found that `firebase-admin` is for server side.

> Is that means i can't use `firebase-admin` and firebase-auth in same
>   project?

How can is use both in my project?

Give me some suggestion for this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58494276 (by the author of the SDK), https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097740, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47581505, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59599189, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59079720 and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+use+firebase+admin+in+android+app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK is not intended for use in Android apps.  It's for backend code running in a controlled server or desktop that you fully control.  Please don't try work around this - instead your Android app should be invoking a backend that uses the Admin SDK to perform the work you need.  It would be a fairly massive security hole for an app to have the Admin SDK and a service account bundled into it, as that leaves your project open to direct, easy abuse by anyone who can download your app and get the service account credentials.